# Loading nuget package sources dynamically depending on environment with Paket

Tags: c#, automation, nuget, paket

I have a C# automation solution which uses internal nuget packages.

Having multiple staging environments I would like to load the nugets depending on the environment I am running on.

If I am on a certain environment I would need to load the packages from a set of sources and so on.

Currently my packet.dependencies looks like this, which is incorrect.

```
source \\Source_for_staging
source \\Source_for_staging
source \\Source_for_staging
source \\Source_for_prod
source \\Source_for_prod
source \\Source_for_prod

nuget nuget1
nuget nuget2
...
```

I would like to know if it is possible, and maybe how it could be done, to have something which basically does the following:

```
if staging
source \\Source_for_staging
source \\Source_for_staging
source \\Source_for_staging
if prod
source \\Source_for_prod
source \\Source_for_prod
source \\Source_for_prod

nuget nuget1
nuget nuget2
...
```

I have done quite a bit of research on the topic but cannot seem to come up with anything except for groups. One thing I did think of is setting up groups, one for prod and another for staging, and finding a way to reference the different groups depending on which environment is being run however this does not seem like the best solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You want different Nuget package sources for different deployments?  That sort of goes against the whole idea of packages.  Your code should build and deploy relative to the environment using transforms and config.

Comment: Yes basically. This is a testing solution which runs the same tests across multiple environments. So when deploying on one environment it would need to use the packages available for that environment. With nuget package manager I used to load the different sources using nuget.targets. So basically I would need to rethink how this is currently being done??

Comment: That's what I'm totally not understanding - *why* you'd need different packages for different environments.  I may be completely off course here, but in my mind a package (and specific version) is a static thing that is always the same everywhere.  I've always used app.config or web.config values for environment specific values, and transform the config file(s) when deploying, as part of the deployment.  Maybe if you could give an example of something that changes in a package from environment to environment it may help clarify.

Comment: It is very possible that I still don't understand how it works but bare with me :) So when a dev makes a change to one of the private nugets the change is not pushed directly to prod. It will be on staging. And I have more than one staging environment. So the change gradually moves up to production. Using the same testing solution I would want that when I run my testing build on a specific environment (using parameters) it would get the correct latest nuget version based on that environment.

Comment: If I have a private MyComp.JSON nuget at version 1.0.0 across all environments and a change has been made on staging to 1.0.1 I want tests done on staging to use 1.0.1 but those done on production to use 1.0.0. The source for staging will contain the newer version while prod will still only contain up to version 1.0.0 (older version)

Comment: The packages won't get pushed to staging or production until you deploy.  Say PackageA.1.1.0 is being used in all environments and you update your development environment to use PackageA1.1.1, then it will never be used anywhere else until you deploy to that environment.  You should definitely always use the same package when you deploy though, or you're changing the build between deployments, which in essence negates all testing you've previously done.

Comment: No the packages are deployed by other teams to different environments. Then I test the sites using a single solution across separate environments. If that makes sense :)

Comment: So multiple packages and multiple sites and 1 automation solution using  dev packages to test, integration testing, e2e testing ecc. Seems like the only way to go about this is cloning across separate branches for each environment and setting up the sources for each branch/environment.

Comment: No, sorry - it doesn't make sense at all.  I'm not sure where your lack of understanding is, whether it's packages or build/deployment but every comment you post just makes the question make less and less sense.  I'm out mate.  Good luck.

Comment: Ok and thanks for your time. I will dig a bit more and see what comes up.